# Make a table in MySQL based on specific values of two other tables?

Tags: mysql, database

For example, I have a table like this:

| ID | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rob | 9 |
| 2 | Anderson | 10 |
| 3 | Lina | 6 |

And another table like this:

| ID | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rob | 5 |
| 2 | Anderson | 8 |
| 3 | Lina | 3 |

And then I want a third table in which the "Score" colunm will be made by de multiplication of the Score of the person in the two other tables, so it would end up like this:

| ID | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rob | 45 |
| 2 | Anderson | 80 |
| 3 | Lina | 18 |

How could I do it ?

Comment: Ever heard of `JOIN`?

Comment: Try `SELECT tb1.ID, tb2.Name, (tb1.Score * tb2.Score) as Score FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE tb1.ID = tb2.ID`

Comment: That made the job, Thank you very much Tamil !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like below into your third table:

```
insert into third_table values(SELECT tb1.ID, tb2.Name, (tb1.Score * tb2.Score) as Score FROM tb1, tb2 WHERE tb1.ID = tb2.ID)
```